# What is the best chemical for cleaning fossils and rocks

Tags: acid-base

I am new to fossil collecting and would like to know what chemical is best for cleaning fossils and rocks of clay deposits. Specific acids/bases

Comment: There can't really be a general answer. The variety of rocks and fossils ot too large for a single, optimal, solution to exist.

Comment: You may want to specify the type of fossil. If it contains pyrite then it will probably require more care. See eg https://www.zoicpalaeotech.de/pages/pyritefossils

Comment: Great comment, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Water is a great chemical with universal usage. Use other chemicals only if justified and you know, what you are doing. Aggressive chemicals like acids may destroy or damage surface layers.

Specifically fossils as various shells may be based on calcium carbonate, what could dissolve in acids.

Consult your more experienced offline or online colleagues or amateurs about their procedures or specific advises.

Consider also practical advises at

- [Earthscience SE site](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) or
- [geo.libretexts.org - Bookshelves](https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves)

Comment: Thank you for you comments